# asp.net mvc with jquery ajax cal HttpPostedFileBase file getting null value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

```
**Jquery Ajax call sending data to controller**

$("#btncareerssubmimt").click(function () {
        var Name = $("#txtname").val();
 var file = $("#fileresume").val();
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Footer/sendmail',              
                data: { Name: Name ,file: file },
                success: function () {

                    $("#simplecareers").html('<p style="color:#74ac12;margin-left:19%;">Your Request Submitted Successfully</p>');
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    $("#simple-msg").html('<pre>"fail"</pre>');

                }
            });
}
```

in aboveo ajax cal iam getting name and file path correctly but when we pass to controller 
getting name only but file path getting null 
        My Html view

```
 <input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname" class="form-control" value=""/>
input type="file" name="file" id="fileresume"  value=""/>
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="btncareerssubmimt" class="submit" />


This is my controller

  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult sendmail(string Name ,HttpPostedFileBase fileresume)
        {
}
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your html to:

```
<form id="formToSendEmail" action="/Footer/sendmail">
   <input type="text" name="Name" id="txtname" class="form-control" value=""/>
   <input type="file" name="fileresume" id="fileresume"  value=""/>
   <input type="button" value="Upload" id="btncareerssubmimt" />
</form>
```

And js:

```
$("#btncareerssubmimt").click(function () {
   $("#formToSendEmail").ajaxSubmit({
               type: "POST",
               success: function () {
                   $("#simplecareers").html('<p style="color:#74ac12;margin-left:19%;">Your Request Submitted Successfully</p>');
               },
               error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                   $("#simple-msg").html('<pre>"fail"</pre>');
               }
           });
}
```

`.ajaxSubmit()` is method from jQuery Form Plugin which helps manage form submit process -  [jQuery Form Plugin](https://github.com/malsup/form).

Comment: Thanks for your replay i tried .ajaxSubmit() and <input type="file" name="fileresume" id="fileresume"  value=""/> but there is no use  when ever i put .ajaxSubmit() iam getting Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)} has no method 'ajaxSubmit' this error

Comment: I edited my answer and now is more completed and more understandable.

Comment: i followed your code -when i click on upload button iam getting Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ajaxSubmit' in firebug

Comment: Sorry i was shure that `.ajaxSubmit()` is part of jQuery, but is part of  jQuery Form Plugin - which simplifies submit forms.

Comment: is there any code regarding sending a attachment file to controller can you help me using only ajax call with out using forms

Comment: please look this thread [jQuery Ajax File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload) to understand ajax file upload process