# FileUpload formData in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, file-upload, webforms

I have some problem with posting formData to server side action method. Because ajax call doesn't send files to server, I have to add file uploader data to formData manually like this
It is impossible to call a server method

```
[WebMethod]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Name(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        string ret = "test";
        return file;
    }
```

Errors on the client side no
I wrote jQuery function that need to post form data to server using ajax call. 
this is my script:

```
data.append(self.idFileInput, file[f]);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "/AddContract.aspx/Name",            
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
```

Any tips, link or code example would be useful.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: string works, but I need to upload files using FormData JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "AddContract.aspx/Name",            
    data: { field1: self.idFileInput, field2 : file[f]} ,
    dataType: 'json',//Remove this line this line is causing issue.
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

Comment: At back end you need to get these params from Request["feild1"]

Comment: How is It? Can example?

Comment: Server method is not called at all if I use FormData.
If you send a string everything works fine

Comment: here is a good example you can have a look. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13700/Simple-AJAX-implementation-for-ASP-NET-Web-applica

Answer (score 0):

In a previous answer I said something stupid about ASPX not supporting `WebMethod` calls, which they do.

Now a real answer:

In order to post a file you need to use the `ajaxSubmit` method. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060075/asp-net-mvc-with-jquery-ajax-cal-httppostedfilebase-file-getting-null-value) reference.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. 
I use iframe, but it is advisable FormData Html5.
FormData works in MVC, but WebForms no